# Center PDF button in DataTables

Tags: datatables, bootstrap-4

I would like to center and align with the search box/page lenght the PDF button I've added to this datatable.

Don't look at the data I've insert in the table, I've just insert one element to reduce the lenght of the code.

This is my code:

```
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <title>Studen</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/css/buttons.bootstrap4.min.css">

    </head>

    <body>
            <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Year</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>John</td>
                        <td>2018</td>                                       
                    </tr> 
                </tbody>
            </table>

            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/buttons.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
                        buttons: ['pdf']
                    });
                    table.buttons().container()
                            .appendTo('#example_wrapper .col-md-6:eq(0)');
                });
            </script>
   </body>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`dom`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) option

- `l` - length changing input control
- `f` - filtering input
- `t` - The table!
- `i` - Table information summary
- `p` - pagination control
- `r` - processing display element
- `r` - processing display element
- `B` - buttons

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    buttons: ['pdf'],
    dom: "<'row'<'col-sm-12 col-md-4'l><'col-sm-12 col-md-4 text-center'B><'col-sm-12 col-md-4'f>>" +
      "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
      "<'row'<'col-sm-12 col-md-5'i><'col-sm-12 col-md-7'p>>",
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/css/buttons.bootstrap4.min.css">

<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Year</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>2018</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/buttons.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script>
```

**Note:** Use `Full page` option to view demo

Comment: Thanks it worked! Is it also possible to align it vertically with the seach box and the "show entries" element?